# math is even harder than javascript

Tags: javascript, math, numbers

so i have a problem in section where you find few "//var"-s. basically I need it to show how many kilogramms and grams will i get if i will eat a specific number of specific burgers. e.g. hamburger is 260 calories = 0,260 kilogramms. 0,260 * 4 portions = 1 kilo 40 grams. but it doesn't show that. shows really rounded numbers. Really need help with this, have been sitting for 3+ hours trying to figure out what's wrong..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body{font-size:150%;}
    </style>
        <title>FAT CALCULATOR 4000</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <script>
             var calories=new Array(0, 260, 310, 460, 560, 400, 370);
             var cals=calories[0];

            function calsMuutus(){
                    cals=calories[document.getElementById("hamburger").selectedIndex];
                    arvuta();
                }
            function arvuta(){
                var kogus1=document.getElementById("kogus").value;
                if(isNaN(kogus1)){
                    document.getElementById("kaal").value="...";
                    return;
                    }


                //var kaal=calsg*kogus;
                var calsg=(cals/1000);  
                //var kogusg=kogus1/1000;
                var kaal=(calsg*kogus1);
                var kaalk=parseInt(kaal);
                var kaalg=parseInt(kaal)%1000;
                var kaal=kaalk+" kg. "+kaalg+" gr.";

                document.getElementById("kaal").value=kaal;
                }
            function arvuta2(){
                var kaal1=document.getElementById("kaal").value;
                if(isNaN(kaal1)){
                    document.getElementById("kogus").value="...";
                    return;
                    }
                var kogus=(kaal1/calsg);
                document.getElementById("kogus").value=kogus;
                }

            </script>
    </head>
    <body background="calc_bg.jpg" >
    <center>

        <div>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <h1>FAT CALCULATOR 4000</h1>
            Choose hamburger<br />
            <select id="hamburger" onchange="calsMuutus()" >
                <option> </option>
                <option>Hamburger</option>
                <option>Cheeseburger</option>
                <option>Double Cheeseburger</option>
                <option>Big Mac</option>
                <option>Filet-O-Fish</option>
                <option>McChicken</option>

            </select><br />
            <p></p>
            Amount: <br />
            <input type="text" id="kogus" onkeyup="arvuta()" /><br />
            <p></p>
            You gain:<br />
            <input type="text" id="kaal" onkeyup="arvuta2()"  /><br />
        </tr>
        </td>
        </table>        
        </div>
    </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And this is why descriptive variable naming is **mandatory**.

Comment: Have you considered putting the calorie value as the value of the options? That way you can get it directly rather than relying on the alignment of two separate arrays of values.

Comment: What does "really rounded numbers" mean?

Comment: arvuta: "Calculate", kogus: "quantity", muutus: "change"

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams—perhaps the names are meaningful in the OP's first language.

Comment: @RobG: I'd say variable names are still problematic in this code, `arvuta, arvuta2, calories, cals, calsg, kaal, kaalk, kaalg, kaal1`. It's not a language issue.

Comment: e.g. kaal - mass, kaalk - mass in kilogramms, kaalg - mass in gramms. I didn't really ask anyone to fix the naming. It works pretty fine. I had a problem in mathematical part of this code.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't have to var every single line.

Secondly, the problem lies here:

```
var kaalk=parseInt(kaal);
var kaalg=parseInt(kaal)%1000;
```

parseInt makes it truncated.

Comment: parseInt doesn't round, it truncates (`parseInt(1.0) == 1`).

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 parseInt   // This would round the numbers to a integer value
```

with

```
parseFloat // which would give you precision.
```

Also think about using javascript to bind the events instead of inline attributes.

**[Updated Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DHy4w/2/)**

**JS**

```
function arvuta() {
    var kogus1 = document.getElementById("kogus").value;
    if (isNaN(kogus1)) {
        document.getElementById("kaal").value = "...";
        return;
    }
    // Keep it as it is as you seem to be 
    // dividing by 1000 anyways
    var calsg = cals;
    // Get Kilo calories
    var kaal = (calsg * kogus1);
    // Get the kg for calories
    var kaalk = Math.floor(parseInt(kaal, 10) / 1000);
    var kaalg = parseFloat(kaal) % 1000;
    var kaal = kaalk + " kg. " + kaalg + " gr.";

    document.getElementById("kaal").value = kaal;
}
```

Comment: Thanx, this did help qite a bit. Now tho it shows that you get 0.26 kg. 0.26 gr. from one burger which weight is 260 gramms or in this case 0,260 kilogramms

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use `parseInt`, which returns an **int**eger.

`parseFloat` can do the trick but don't use it, because both `parseInt` and `parseFloat` are slow because they parse strings into numbers, while you want to convert a number to string!

Then, you should use `toFixed`:

```
myNumber.toFixed(numDecimals)
```

Alternatively, you could also use

```
myNumber.toPrecision(numDigits)
```

Examples

```
(123.456).toFixed(7);     // "123.4560000"  (7 decimals)
(123.456).toPrecision(7); // "123.4560"     (7 digits)
(123.456).toFixed(0);     // "123"          (converted to integer)
(123.456).toPrecision(0); // RangeError: precision 0 out of range
```